# Angular 4 to Angular 7 - Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I saw many people have asked this question but couldn't find a working solution in them. So before down voting take a moment to read the question. I have transformed my code from Angular 4 to Angular 7. The code complied successfully. But when the site is loaded under the localhost the browser console log the following error :

I can't understand from where this error is generated, from the `ng2-tag-input` or from elsewhere. It says in the document that now the `ng2-tag-input` have been replaced by the `ngx-chip`. When I change the tags into it, the browser says

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'HomeModule'
>
> details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:4200 has 
>   not been whitelisted for client ID 
>   28*******-65h8***************3t4.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to 
>   https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your 
>   project's client ID."
>   error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed

Can someone point out the why this is generated?

Comment: did you import any 3rd party module  from npm package  in HomeModule? Could you  show homeModules imports

Comment: sure!! I add it to the question! thank you @kunalverma

Comment: it says This package has been renamed to 'ngx-chips'. Please install it instead. on ng2-tag-input  documentation     ...which package did you installed ng2-tag-input or 'ngx-chips'

Comment: Use `ngx-tags-input` instead of `ng2-tag-input` since `ng2-tag-input` also imports `style` from core (`__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["style"]`)

Comment: https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips  <-could Help ..Use import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';

Comment: If you installed new one then   import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';

Comment: @yurzui `ngx-tags-input` says it have no `TagInputModule` in it

Comment: @kunalverma when i use `ngx-chips` the errors i have displayed in the latter of the question arises

Comment: `import { TagsInputModule } from 'ngx-tags-input/dist';`

Comment: is it installed corectly [npm package]  "ng2-tags-input package has been renamed to ngx-tags-input, please change your package.json. " mentioned on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tags-input

Comment: @kunalverma yeah! I used the npn install ngx-chips

Comment: Is it installed  propertly . Are you able to locate it in node_modules ?@ Osh

Comment: import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';

Comment: import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // this is needed!
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 
@NgModule({
   imports: [
       TagInputModule, 
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule
       ...OtherModules 
   ] // along with your other modules
})
export class AppModule {}

Comment: Last thing Could you post @NgModule decorator 's Content

Comment: in the question :)

Comment: you will have to share complete project via some source, because it needs more debugging.

Comment: `import { TagsInputModule } from 'ngx-tags-input/dist';`

Comment: @kunalverma somehow the 'ngx-chips' seems to be working now. followed the documentation to the dot. thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you get `google clientId` you should declare the `whitelist` URLs, and you didn't add `http://localhost:4200`...